# Why can't I Vote to Close a question which was reopened?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060908/how-to-filter-an-array-of-dictionaries-with-nspredicate) as duplicate of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824573/how-to-sort-an-array-which-contains-dictionaries) as the OP's requirements first stated that he wanted the same thing as asked in the second question.

After closing of the Post (By me and a Gold badge holder), OP said he had been mistaken in expressing his intent (He wanted to filter, not sort). Admittedly, I just saw his statement of purpose, spotted the line of code causing the crash, told him the reason behind the crash and VTC'd.

Anyways So  another Gold Badge user reopened the post and answered it.

The *New Question* was still a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250575/objective-c-filter-array-of-nsdictionarys-and-nsdictionarys).

But now when I try to VTC it again, I can't cast a vote.

[image]

Why can't I vote to close now?

*What is the rationale behind not allowing previous Close Voters to cast another Close-vote on a reopened post?*

Comment: i believe it's to prevent the same people VTCing it again leading to an endless loop of closing and reopening by the same people until someone get's tired and gives up

Comment: @Memor-X Then why do we have review queues? They solely exist to make sure that only valid and legitimate Votes get through and no one could game the system?

Comment: from my understanding *most* review queues are to help in maintain quality content such as being able to see when older questions/answer which have gotten lost under all the other posts get flagged (ie. like old duplicates or questions which used to be on-topic but now aren't.). i don't think a the review queue would stop rapid closing/reopenings similar to [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/342440/revisions?page=5)

Comment: @Memor-X Hmm well makes sense. Care to make it an answer?

Comment: Still kinda annoyed that the other user just reopened the post and answered it instead of closing it as duplicate of other question which he must have known was a duplicate (As basic questions are almost always already asked) but guess that's another issue.

Comment: @NSNoob `They solely exist to make sure that only valid and legitimate Votes get through and no one could game the system?`  No, that's not their purpose at all.  They exist to help people who are looking to review content quickly and conveniently find content that needs reviewing.  Without the queues actually finding the content to review on the site would be more difficult, particularly for people who don't know where/how to look for it.  The review queues tend to be *more* open to abuse than actions taken outside of the queue, for exactly the reason that they're more convenient.

Comment: Because in such cases you need to open a meta discussion, not re-close.

Comment: Look at your sceen shot: it says "you voted 10 minutes ago"

Comment: @ThomasWeller I know what it says. The question is about _The rationale_ behind this policy which the other commentators and the answerer have explained.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Why can't I Vote to Close a question again after it was reopened?

This check is in place to avoid "close-wars" as [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346064/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-which-was-reopened#comment460088_346064) above by Memor-X. The system wants a different group of users to decide if a post needs to be closed again (even if the closure reason is different).

The official reason is mentioned by Shog9♦ on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106697/):

> This restriction exists because when it didn't exist folks would get into "close-wars", wherein the same sets of users would repeatedly re-open and re-close controversial questions. Yes, it does break use-cases where questions must be closed repeatedly. Fortunately, those are less common.

Comment: Note that if you vote to close a question and your vote expires before the question is closed, you can cast it again, even if the question is closed and re-opened inbetween doing so.

Comment: New movie: "Stack Wars: The Close Wars"