# Revoting for a duplicate is not possible, how should that case be handled?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

If I voted a question to be a duplicate to another question, the question was closed due to that and was later reopened by a person with a gold badge to one of the tags, there is no way to cast any new vote for closing that question as duplicate again.

The reason why recasting a vote it not possible is to avoid **close-wars** as mentioned here
[Why can't I Vote to Close a question which was reopened?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346064/why-cant-i-vote-to-close-a-question-which-was-reopened).

But what should be done in this case if I still think that this is a duplicate to another question, especially if the answers to the current question are basically identical to the one previously voted as duplicate?

Raising a flag is not valid in this case and was declined with:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

So the only option here is to write a comment, which might not be seen if more comments come over time, or (what I did) to copy the IMHO best answer of the original duplicate write it as an own answer, with slight improvements. And linking the original answer/question in my answer. But that doesn't seem to be correct either.

So the question is, should I write only a comment in this case, linking to the - in my opinion - duplicate? Or should I, if I think that a certain answer to this duplicate is better than the answers currently given in the new question, write it as an answer myself for better visibility?

Comment: what is the question?